# Serial monitor disconnecting itself

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

Problem: can't print to the serial monitor, it appears that the serial monitor disconnects itself after uploading a program.

I'm brand new to arduino, and I'm trying to upload a basic program to print to the serial monitor.

I use an arduino uno and my OS is Ubuntu.
I am connecting the arduino to my PC via USB.
Using Arduino Studio Release 0.0.5 experimental build 0.0.5-16058

(I am able to communicate via the digital output pins, tested by making a simple circuit to make the led light blink)

Here is the program:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.print("test");
    delay(500);
}
```

Here is the result of the build, look at the last line and it says the serial monitor was disconnected? Why would this happen automatically?

```
[2/2/2016 8:51:26 PM] - Start Building
[2/2/2016 8:51:26 PM] - CPP File Created [/tmp/build1454471486915/test.cpp]
[2/2/2016 8:51:26 PM] - test.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:26 PM] - CDC.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - HID.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - HardwareSerial.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - HardwareSerial0.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - HardwareSerial1.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - HardwareSerial2.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - HardwareSerial3.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - IPAddress.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - Print.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - Stream.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - Tone.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - USBCore.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - WInterrupts.c compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - WMath.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - WString.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - abi.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - hooks.c compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - main.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:27 PM] - new.cpp compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring.c compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring_analog.c compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring_digital.c compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring_pulse.c compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring_shift.c compiled
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - CDC.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - HID.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - HardwareSerial.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - HardwareSerial0.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - HardwareSerial1.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - HardwareSerial2.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - HardwareSerial3.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - IPAddress.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - Print.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - Stream.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - Tone.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - USBCore.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - WInterrupts.c.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - WMath.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - WString.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - abi.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - hooks.c.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - main.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - new.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - test.cpp.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - test.ino linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring.c.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring_analog.c.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring_digital.c.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring_pulse.c.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - wiring_shift.c.o linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - test.cpp.elf linked to core.a
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - test EEPROM
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - test.hex builded
[2/2/2016 8:51:28 PM] - Uploading...
[2/2/2016 8:51:30 PM] - Uploaded
[2/2/2016 8:51:30 PM] - [arduino ide - serial monitor] Serial monitor connected to /dev/ttyACM0
[2/2/2016 8:51:36 PM] - [arduino ide - serial monitor] Serial monitor disconnected from /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: Are you using the Arduino IDE? If so, what version? If not, what are you using?

Comment: Yes, ArduinoStudio Release 0.0.5 experimental build 0.0.5-16058

Comment: Does the serial monitor disconnect when you hold open the monitor and after that hold the reset button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your IDE is doing that, but the official Arduino IDE from [Arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc/) works on Ubuntu and does not have that issue. Download from [Arduino Software download page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software).

Comment: I thought arduino studio was the official IDE, I'll download it and try it when I get home. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @JamesWierzba "Arduino Studio" is from Arduino.org, whereas this answer links to the standard IDE produced by Arduino.cc. Neither is more official than the other; the original Arduino company split into two factions and are now offering competing products and software.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that I was referring to the version from Arduino.cc. Arduino.cc has a forum where you can ask questions like that. Arduino.org does not appear to have a forum (as far as I can see).

Comment: I downloaded the Arduino IDE you suggested and printing to the serial monitor now works. Thanks